# 404 not found spring boot web application on oracle weblogic server 12c

Tags: spring-boot, weblogic, weblogic12c, custom-error-pages

I'm trying to develop a simple web application that returns my name after passing it as a parameter. using spring boot REST API
while using java spring boot 2.6.5.
I have successfully deployed it on oracle WebLogic server version 12.2.1.0 "12c".
all the deployment steps are successful while it's in an active state on the WebLogic console.
however, after testing it, I get the 404 not found an error

Comment: Is there any information in the logs regarding this?

Comment: i'm new in working on the weblogic ; how can i find the logs ?